# Can I get a specific property of each element of a collection using only object specifiers?

Tags: applescript

Say I have a collection. Can I get a list of the values for a specific property of elements of the collection using only [object specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW7) (e.g. no [looping statement](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-127362))? If so, how? For example, take a list of records:

```
set stuff to {{foo:"bar"}, {foo:"baz"}, {foo:"bam"}}
```

For this example, the result should be the list of the values of the `foo` property:

```
{"bar", "baz", "bam"}
```

To illustrate what I mean by "only object specifiers", the statement to generate this list should look something like:

```
foo of each item of stuff
```

except there's no such thing as an `each` reference form. Answers that use `repeat` get no points. A "No, you can't do that" answer, if it includes sufficient evidence, is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [filter reference form](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BAJJHEFE) specifies application objects only and can't be used on regular AppleScript objects such as lists or records, so you would have to use an application to do the filtering on one of its objects, for example

```
tell application "System Events" to return value of every property list item of property list items of (make new property list item with properties {value:stuff}) whose name is "foo"
```

An alternative would be to use **AppleScriptObjC** (via something like a Cocoa-AppleScript applet or [ASObjC Runner](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/runner.html)), where you can use NSArray's **valueForKey:** method, for example

```
set stuff to current application's NSArray's arrayWithArray_({{foo:"bar"}, {foo:"baz"}, {foo:"bam"}})
stuff's valueForKey_("foo") as list
```

Comment: Just want to add a minor tweak to your first example, to add

set theResult to {}
repeat with theItem in filteredResults
  set the end of theResult to first item of theItem
end repeat